# Why is Typescript tsc out generating files not in my repo

Tags: node.js, typescript

This is my repository
https://github.com/inspiraller/tsc-example

This is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "allowJs": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["dom", "es6", "es5", "es2017", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "declaration": true,
    "rootDir": "./",
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "__tests__", "jest.config.js"],
  "include": [ "/src/*", "@types"]
}
```

This is my index.ts

```
type mystring = string;

type TFunc = (x: mystring) => string;

const func: TFunc = (str) => str + str;

const get = () => func('hello');

export default get;
```

My `package.json` just has one package - `typescript`, and a script to build

```
{
  "name": "tsc-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  }
}
```

When I run build like this

```
npm run build
```

I get this error:

```
error TS6059: File '/src/config.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'c:/projects/tsc-example'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

error TS6059: File '/src/hot.tsx' is not under 'rootDir' 'c:/projects/droplets/tsc-example'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

error TS6059: File '/src/index.tsx' is not under 'rootDir' 'c:/projects/droplets/tsc-example'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.


Found 3 errors.
```

It does try to generate these files, but they are not in this repo, and they are not even in any ancestor of this project. (Having looked at the generated output I can see that the content of these files, are coming from another repo I have, but they are not inside this project)

- config.d.ts
- config.js
- config.js.map
- hot.d.ts
- hot.js
- hot.js.map
- index.d.ts
- index.js
- index.js.map

Can anyone help explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You indicated a path with leading `/` here `"include": [ "/src/*", "@types"]`. Just remove it like this:

```
 "include": [ "src/*", "@types"]
```